# How to Ignore Catalog Pricing Rule when applying Shopping Cart Price Rule?

Tags: magento-1.8, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules, promotions

I have an ongoing 50% Off Catalog Pricing Rule currently active across my store. A few days back I have also distributed coupon codes on a Radio show with 25% Off. Now i have a situation where customers with these codes are applying the code and receiving a double discount. My $10 product is selling for $3.75 (50% + 25%).

I want a functionality where when the customer applies the coupon code, the code does apply but ONLY on the original price of $10. Thereby selling the product at $7.5. It should overlook the catalog rule. So the customer can choose to either go with the Catalog discount or Coupon discount but not both. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome Sir @Angelo Soares,+1 upvote

Answer (score 3):

The problem you described is related to difference in logic of catalog price rule vs shopping cart price rule.

Catalog Price Rule - is defining a unit price of a product and affect product view/listing pages, it works the same way as special price functionality, but on a group of products.
This functionality is taken to find a final price, that is calculated on as minimal value from such options: product price, special price, tier price, group price, catalog rule price.

Shopping Cart Price Rule - is affecting a final price that you have already in a shopping card, there is no relation, if it is a rule or a tier or a group product price.

In your situation there are only two options, that you can choose, in order to not sell products that cheap:

- Remove catalog product price and make 50% shopping cart price rule for your sale products. In this case you should specify that shopping cart price rule processing should be stopped after applying 50% discount. Also sort order of it should be a high number. Also for your special coupon code discount, you need to do the same, but sort order should be lower then 50% rule, it can be applied first. In this case, if coupon is specified - only 25% rule is applied, otherwise 50% discount rule.
- Add products that are under your catalog price rule as an exemtion from 25% discount. For this purpose you'll need to specify the same conditions as in your catalog price rule, but with a logical NOT combination.

If you'd like to learn more about the pricing logic in Magento you can check one of my presentation on the conference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dzf7lypb9gs