# Coupon code that changes the pricing to group pricing

Tags: product, coupon-codes, pricing

I got interesting task. The website has normal pricing and wholesale pricing (group pricing). Wholesale pricing is per product (not all products have them).

Is anyone aware of any way to create a coupon code in Magento, that when entered on checkout, would select wholesale pricing (group pricing) rather than normal price? (obviously without custom module which could always be made)

Answer (score 0):

Magento *Group Price, Trier Price, Catalog Price*  and *Sales Rules* are different things.

*Group Price, Trier Price, Catalog Price rules* can be used to selectively put products on sale under certain conditions. Catalog price rules does not use coupon codes, because they are triggered before a product is placed into the shopping cart.

**Catalog Price Rule** - `is defining a unit price of a product and affect product view/listing pages, it works the same way as special price functionality, but on a group of products. This functionality is taken to find a final price, that is calculated on as minimal value from such options: product price, special price, tier price, group price, catalog rule price.`

**Shopping Cart Price Rule** `is affecting a final price that you have already in a shopping card, there is no relation, if it is a rule or a tier or a group product price.`

Whenever a product cart then a item in cart called as `Quote item(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item)` not as  `product item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)`.

As per magento system coupon  rules is depends on  `Quote item(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item)  not product item Price`.

Here a question  it describe properly.

[How to Ignore Catalog Pricing Rule when applying Shopping Cart Price Rule?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53472/how-to-ignore-catalog-pricing-rule-when-applying-shopping-cart-price-rule)

Comment: Thanks. But in theory Shopping Cart Price rule is calculated on the fly when you visit shopping cart (it's not taken from DB), so it would be possible to apply the rule (even worst case custom module) that if you use the code Shopping Cart Price rule would use Group Price as well (despite you're not in group) and then in a standard way take the lowest price which in this case would be Group Price. Or is my thinking incorrect?