# Disable free shipping with Catalog Price Rule

Tags: magento-1, catalog-price-rules, ce-1.8.1.0, free-shipping

we use magento 1.8.1CE

People now get Free shipping over 49,95 (with free shipping shipment method)

But we want to disable this when a product gets a special price (defined by a catalog price rule).

But when they have a mixed cart ....
With some Sale items and some Not-Sale items, and the none sale items get over the 49,95 the free shipping is applied.

What i would like to have ...
Is that the free shipping is only being calculated with non-sale items.

Can this be done in magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in the opposite way.

First I had set the free shipping At 49,95. For all collections.
In this way I couldn't exclude the sale items.

I have given de sale items an extra attribute. Sale in my case
Yes for sale, no for not sale.

I now have set the free shipping At 99,95. (The desired free shipping with sale items)

Then I have made a free shipping cart rule (without a specific code) for getting free shipping At 49,95 with an extra rule. All items who have the attribute sale = no get free shipping At 49,95.

Answer (score 1):

There is no relation between catalog rules and shipping methods. Basically shipping charges are applied after product and cart item prices.

**Magento does not have a feature "Disable free shipping with Catalog Price Rule" by default.**

See this link for further explanation: [How to Ignore Catalog Pricing Rule when applying Shopping Cart Price Rule?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53472/how-to-ignore-catalog-pricing-rule-when-applying-shopping-cart-price-rule)

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping` and override the method `collectRates()`.

There you have to replace the following code

```
if (($request->getFreeShipping())
    || ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >=
        $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal'))
) {
```

with

```
if (($request->getFreeShipping())
    || ($this->_getSubTotalForFreeShipping($request) >=
        $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal'))
) {
```

and add this new method:

```
protected function _getSubTotalForFreeShipping(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    $subTotal = $request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax();
    foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getFinalPrice() < $item->getPrice()) {
            $subTotal -= $item->getFinalPrice();
        }
    }
    return $subTotal;
}
```

This should subtract the price of all special price items from the value that is compared with the free shipping treshold.

Untested code, I am not sure, if `$item->getFinalPrice() < $item->getPrice()` is really sufficient to determine products with applied catalog rules.